# How to use “command” in canvas_image just like in Button ? Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a code that is working perfectly, but I want a clickable functionality in my image so that it will redirect to frame.

```
from tkinter import * 

def onObjectClick1(event):
    print("1")
    canv.itemconfig(obj1, image=my_pic2)
    canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<Leave>', onObjectClick2)     

def onObjectClick2(event):
    print("2")
    canv.itemconfig(obj1, image=my_pic1)
    canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<Enter>', onObjectClick1)        
    
root = Tk()    
canv = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
my_pic1 = PhotoImage(file="start000-before.png")
my_pic2 = PhotoImage(file="start000-after.png")

obj1 = canv.create_image(50,50,image=my_pic1, anchor=NW)
canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<Enter>', onObjectClick1)        
canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<Leave>', onObjectClick2)        
canv.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Please help me out, I'm new in Tkinter.

Comment: What is the problem? Are you not able to understand the Code you have written?

Comment: No, I am understanding the code. But I'm confuse how to use Button in the canvas so that I can use command attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `create_window()` to put a `Button` inside a `Canvas`:

```py
from tkinter import * 

def on_click():
    print('button clicked')

root = Tk()    

canv = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canv.pack()

my_pic1 = PhotoImage(file="start000-before.png")
my_pic2 = PhotoImage(file="start000-after.png")

btn = Button(canv, image=my_pic1, command=on_click)
btn.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: btn.config(image=my_pic2))        
btn.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: btn.config(image=my_pic1))        

canv.create_window(50, 50, window=btn, anchor=NW)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Bunch of thanks! it's working!!! But Now I'm facing problem with the background that is not showing transparent as what it was showing before :(

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you are binding to the Enter and Leave events. To bind to the click event you need to use Button-1

```
canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<Button-1>', onMouseButton1Click)
```

The canvas and canvas widgets don't support the `command` property as other tkinter widgets.

You can create a window inside a tkinter canvas which can contain normal tkinter widgets. In the below example, I create a window which contains a button. This can then use `command` in the normal way

```
from tkinter import * 

def PressMeCmd():
    print("You pressed me")
    
root = Tk()    
canv = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)

button = Button(canv,text="Press Me",command=PressMeCmd)

window = canv.create_window(0,0,window=button)

canv.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I apologize for not being clear, but I want to use `Button` instead of `canvas_image` inside Canvas in order to use `command` attribute so that I can redirect it to another frame.

Comment: @sodmzs1 I've updated my answer to show how to create a button inside a canvas using the create_window option.

Comment: Thank you for the clear example.. But my code is changing image when the user hover on the image and turns back to the previous one when the user take away his cursor. So you mean I should remove the `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` and put '<Button-1>' instead ? I'm literally confused.. can you please update my code with the solution ?

Comment: @sodmzs1 You aren't asking very clear questions. Do you want a button or do you want images that change when you hover over them? If you want both, then just add your code that creates the images. Perhaps you can update your original question with a few more details of what you expect your tkinter program to do.

Comment: I apologize! Yes I want both. currently my code is just working for hover over them. But I want the use to click on image so that it will execute `PressMeCmd()`

Comment: @sodmzs1 There are two options. Forget about the images and just use the Button with it's built in `command` property OR use the images and use the bind to `<Button-1>` to make it call a function when it is clicked. Buttons themselves can have images.